# Why Google Chart does not work ASP MVC app?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I have method on my controller, who return Json

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CompanyChart()
        {

            var data = db.adusers;
            var selectUsers = from s in data where (s.Company != null) select s;
            int fenixPlus = (from fP in data where (fP.Company == "ООО \"Феникс+\"") select fP).Count();
            int fenixPresent = (from fP in data where (fP.Company == "ООО \"Феникс-Презент\"") select fP).Count();

            var dataObj = new object[]
            {
                new object[] {"Компания","Количество"},
                new object[] { "ООО \"Феникс+\"", fenixPlus},
                new object[] { "ООО \"Феникс-Презент\"", fenixPresent}
            };

            return Json(dataObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Json looks like this
 `[["Компания","Количество"],["ООО \"Феникс+\"",53],["ООО \"Феникс-Презент\"",42]]`

In my view side  I have a  jquery post request

```
  $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CompanyChart", "Users")',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    drawChart(data);
                }
            });
```

Then, I try draw google pie chart

```
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart(data) {

                var array = JSON.parse(data);
                var dataV = new google.visualization.DataTable(array);
                var options = {
                    title: 'My Daily Activities',
                    pieHole: 0.4,
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
                chart.draw(dataV, options);
            };
```

Not work, error in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token К in JSON at position 0`

I don't understand, why my code does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonResult` returns to the caller a JSON `object` not a string of JSON content, therefore, you don't need to call `JSON.parse`.

Simply change

```
var array = JSON.parse(data);
```

to

```
var array = data;
```

Comment: Not work Now console write  Index:1711 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined
VM372:231 Uncaught Error: Not an array

Comment: Can you post the code where it is erroring, specifically "VM372:231"?